# winapi's LoadImage() alway returns NULL

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I've tried to load a bmp image using LoadImage() in order to display it, but I just can't find a way to load the image. Here is some code:

## EDIT

as suggested, here is a runnable example

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

std::string GetLastErrorAsString()
{
    //Get the error message, if any.
    DWORD errorMessageID = ::GetLastError();
    if (errorMessageID == 0)
        return std::string(); //No error message has been recorded

    LPSTR messageBuffer = nullptr;
    size_t size = FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL, errorMessageID, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPSTR)&messageBuffer, 0, NULL);

    std::string message(messageBuffer, size);

    //Free the buffer.
    LocalFree(messageBuffer);

    return message;
}


int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpszArgument, int iShow) {

    std::ofstream file("output.txt");
    
    HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, L"C:\\yes.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 300, 300, LR_LOADFROMFILE);

    if (hBitmap == NULL) {
        file << "error: " << GetLastErrorAsString().c_str() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        file << "success." << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And this result is always NULL. If I put a wrong file name, the error message will be `The system cannot find the file specified.` but if the name is right, there is simply no error message.

I've tried to save the bmp file in 24 and 32 bits, I played with the `LR_` flags, it doesn't change anything.

I also tried setting the HINSTANCE to the main's one, without any success.

I run this code once at the beginning of the main.

Thanks for your help, I hope I just misunderstood how this works

Comment: If there's no error message then `hBitmap` can't be equal to `NULL`. What makes you think that `hBitmap` is always `NULL`? Can you please try to create an [mcve] to show us?

Comment: I added an example. `hBitmap` is always `NULL` and if the path is valid, `GetLastError()` is set to 0.

Comment: *" but if the name is right, there is simply no error message"* to clear up the confusion that remains from the prior comment, when you say that, you mean `error:` is dumped to the file, but there is no actual message afterward ? Is that correct? Or is simply nothing dumped to the file and the process terminates? It's important, so please clarify.

Comment: @WhozCraig it's correct, `error:` is dumped without message afterward. I verified and `GetLastError()` is equal to 0 too.

Comment: You are calling [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360.aspx) at a time where it doesn't return a meaningful value. Read the documentation again, and put the call where it will return a meaningful value. Or simply add a debug watch with the expression `@err,hr` and single-step over the `LoadImage` call.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm not sure if I am using `GetLastError()` correctly, but if the file name isn't valid, `GetLastError()`returns the right value.

Comment: You *are* calling it incorrectly. As the documentation states: *"You should call the `GetLastError` function **immediately** when a function's return value indicates that such a call will return useful data."* Your code has several calls to `operator<<` interspersed. You don't need any of that, if you use your debugger effectively (as long as you understand the protocol of `GetLastError` which is the same as the `@err` pseudo variable).

Comment: You can also set *cx* and *cy* to 0. Also make sure that you are loading a *valid* BMP file (as opposed to some other graphics format renamed to \*.bmp). To make sure you have a valid BMP file, load it up in MS Paint, and save it from there.

Comment: @IInspectable I am so sorry, it was not a valid BMP file. I created it and saved it from GIMP, and I thought everything was right but it wasn't. Saving it with MS Paint fixed it. About `GetLastError()` You are certainly right about the `operator<<`, I didn't think about it.